# I have a query with give the output as year and month between start date and end date

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query with give the output as year and month between start date and end date..

Query:

```
SELECT lease.lease_start_date,
lease.lease_end_date,
(lease.lease_end_date - lease.lease_start_date) YEAR TO MONTH AS year_months 
FROM lease_header lease
```

Output:

```
start_date  End_date    Year-Month
03-OCT-18   16-NOV-18   +00-01
28-SEP-18   28-SEP-19   +01-00
03-OCT-18   31-DEC-19   +01-03
```

From this output i will take only year-month to show in my screen, now it will show like
0 year 1 month but i need to show only months if the year is zero otherwise show both year and month.

I need output like below:

```
if the year is 0 then show as 1 month
if the year is not 0 then show as 1 year 0 month
```

Answer (score 0):

Well your base query supplies the desired result. Then you get to play the *jump thru hoops to get the display* game. First separate the years-months into individual columns then apply `case` to get year(s) text segment and concatenate the months segment.

```
with lease_header (start_date, end_date) as 
   ( select to_date('03-OCT-18', 'dd-mon-rr'), to_date('16-NOV-18', 'dd-mon-rr') from dual union all  
     select to_date('28-SEP-18', 'dd-mon-rr'), to_date('28-SEP-19', 'dd-mon-rr') from dual union all 
     select to_date('03-OCT-18', 'dd-mon-rr'), to_date('31-DEC-19', 'dd-mon-rr') from dual 
    ) 
-- your query starts here 
select start_date
     , end_date
     , case when yrs = 0 
            then null
            else to_char(yrs) || ' year ' 
       end 
     || to_char(mth) || ' month' year_months           
  from (
         select start_date
              , end_date
              , extract (year from yr_mth) yrs
              , extract (month from yr_mth) mth
           from ( 
                  select start_date
                       , end_date  
                       , ( end_date -  start_date) year to month  as yr_mth
                    from lease_header lease
                )
       );
```

Comment: Did the above answer solve your issue? If so please accept it. This helps future users having the same or similar issue, and removes it from the unanswered queue. Please do not leave a successfully answered question as unanswered. If it did not solve your issue then what remains?